# destinationSource.getQueues() not returning correct number of queues

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I would like to know why the code below is not fetching the correct number of queues. My broker has 25 queues and the code below is returning only 1 queue always.

```
import java.util.Set;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.advisory.DestinationSource;
import org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue;
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, InterruptedException {


         ConnectionFactory out = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
          ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) out.createConnection();

          connection.start();
          Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
          DestinationSource ds = connection.getDestinationSource();
          Set<ActiveMQQueue> amqs = ds.getQueues();
          System.out.println("Number of Queues on Broker:"+amqs.size());
          session.close();
          connection.close();       
    }
```

ds.getQueues(); is always returning only 1 queue though there is 25 queue on the broker. Is there a way to fetch the correct number of queues using this approach.

Comment: maybe your other queues are temporary ? Try calling ds. getTemporaryQueues() as well and see if both numbers add up to 25

Comment: Have you tried delaying the call to get the queue to give the source time to be notified of all active queues, the create is not synchronous

Comment: @Axel Podehl  I tried with  ds.getTemporaryQueues(), Its still the same. But the strange thing if I point to different environment activeMQ broker apart from my local I am able to get the proper number of queues.

Comment: As @TimBish said - DestinationSource needs time to gather information of all queues (by subscribing to advisory topics). You need to keep it running for some small amount of time before using it. https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/57795bafcea290c6879bb288822435c480a9212d/activemq-client/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/advisory/DestinationSource.java